# Date is expected to be in ISO 8601 format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff-HH:MM

Tags: php, time, datetime-format

i need to convert this (`2015-09-30 05:47:58`) time format into ISO 8601 format, i have tried googling and lot of code examples, but no luck, final format for API is `2015-09-30T07:06:21.5663224Z`, appreciate help

```
    $date = new DateTime(); 
    echo $new_date = $date->setISODate($order->getPickupDate());
    echo $PickupDate = $date->format(DateTime::ATOM);
```

I want to `YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff-HH:MM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function getTime($timestamp) {
    return date ( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s' . substr ( ( string ) microtime (), 1, 8 ) . ' P', $timestamp ); //instead of P use \Z if zulu time needed UTC.
}

    $date = new DateTime ();
    //$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC")); 
    $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp ();
    echo getTime ( $timestamp );
```

Comment: Thanks Liviu,this has worked for me with bit customization,  date( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'. substr ( ( string ) microtime (), 1, 8 ) , strtotime($order->getPickupDate()) )

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use Date function of php

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s h:i A",strtotime($order->getPickupDate()));
```

For more options see on http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php